# Запрет сайтов

Tags: роутер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как заблокировать vk.com через роутер. Надо, чтобы моя жена лазя на планшете через `Wi-Fi` не могла посещать контакт. Может какая программа есть?

Comment: лучше наладьте контакт с женой, наличие у члена семьи зависимости от социальных сетей является симптомом а не проблемой самой по себе. Лето вот настало, сходите погуляйте и прочее.

Answer (score 1):

Настройки роутера - IPFilter.Тут нужно начать с того что за роутер. И как попасть в настройки (стандартные ли данные для входа)

Comment: Роутер "Промcвязь М-200 А" от провайдера ByFly.

Comment: Ну тогда вперед, заходите http://192.168.1.1вбивайте логин пароль (admin-admin) если вам не меняли, если меняли, узнавайте у провайдера, и там ищите в настройках. У них должно быть что-то наподобии "Access Management"'a

Comment: Не в этом модеме такого нету. Нужна прога

Answer (score 1):

Ищите в настройках роутера вкладку `Access Management`, далее - `Filter`, и далее - `URL Filter`. 
Там можно устанавливать запреты.

Comment: Там все есть, но вот URL Filter там к сожалению нету (((

Answer (score 1):

Ну если роутер не имеет такого функционала попробуйте всё разрулить правами доступа к hosts, создав в нём запись 127.0.0.1 vk.com. Однако, сильно не обольщайтесь, если ваша жена знает, что такое анонимайзеры, то легко обойдёт установленные вами запреты, будь они хоть на роутере, хоть на самом планшете ;)

Comment: Так ведь если внести такую запись `127.0.0.1 vk.com.` мне в ноут, то в таком случае только я не смогу лазить в контакт, ведь на вайфай это не повлияет. Это получаеться надо как то делать что бы я был раздающим вайфай

Comment: 1. Вы говорили о планшете жены, про ваш ноут речь не шла ;)2. Вобщем-то при определённых настройках можно сделать и так, чтобы вай-фай раздавал роутер, а адресами рулил отдельный узел, ну например, DNS-сервис, установленный хоть на буке, хоть на другом компе, важно чтобы он был постоянно доступен.3. Всё-таки помните, что таким образом запрещать "хождение" в социалки очень малоэффективно. Попробуйте (если вопрос так уж критичен) покопать в сторону формы POST/GET-запросов на социалки, вот их -по-моему мнению - гораздо проще будет отследить и отфильтрвать, если что - обращайтесь

Answer (score 0):

Вот из-за таких вещей и следует покупать нормальные рутеры...
Я из-за предполагавшихся ограничений в отношении сына сразу купил Zyxell Kinetic Lite (который со второй версией прошивки, которая а-ля Циска, может создавать листы запретов (акцесс-листы) для конкретных адресов во внутренней сети (в этом случае, например, контакт мне доступен, а сыну нет)), даже не рассматривая, что предлагает провайдер.
Такого рода роутер в любом случае для семьи необходим.

Comment: Уважаемый, вы всё-таки обратите внимание, что если ваш сын начнёт малость разбираться в IP-технологиях, то даже этот роутер его не ограничит в желании выйти на нужные ему ресурсы

Comment: а может попробовать роутер перепрошить?

Comment: danila - ну рутер-то у меня не в открытом доступе...